# dropdown is getting populated and not getting trimmed

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically populating the dropdown using jquery . Its working fine but every time it executes it adds to the dropdownlist and it doesnot remove the previous values from the dropdown.

Code I am using to dynamiccally populate the dropdown is :

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
                $("#diselc").change(function(){ 
                    fillOptions('diselc','diselchild'); 
                    }); 
            }); 
            function fillOptions(parentId,ddId) {
                alert("atleast the call is being made in the fillOptions"+ddId);
                var dd = $('#' + ddId); 
                alert("the value being passed is "+dd);
                var jsonURL = '/docRuleTool/DataRetrival.do?disease_name='+ $('#' + parentId + ' :selected').val(); 
                $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(opts)
                {
                alert("just after calling the servlet stuff ");
                    $('>option', dd).remove(); // Clean old options first. 
                    if (opts) { 
                        $.each(opts, function(key, value) { 
                            dd.append($('<option/>').val(key).text(value)); 
                        }); 
                    } else { 
                        dd.append($('<option/>').text("Please select parent")); 
                    } 
                }); 


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector used to clear the old options contains a syntax error.  Replace `$('>option', dd).remove()` with `dd.empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/e59rp/). However, the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) state the following:

> Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future
>   release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative
>   selectors.

So I would suggest using `empty` as already shown in other answers. An alternative would be to get all the child `option` elements and remove them. This is pretty much equivalent to what you already have, but using the `children` method instead of the child selector:

```
dd.children("option").remove();
```

Comment: when i used  "dd.children("option").remove();
" nothing is showing off in the dropdown